# Difficulty Installing XNA Game Studio 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: xna, installation

Does anyone know how to properly install XNA Game Studio 4.0 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ? I have been having trouble getting the XNA Game Studio to recognize the Visual Studio. I read that once installed you should be able to run Visual Studio from under the XNA folder in the Start Menu, but I found no such option. I have an assignment due in a couple of days and I'm really in a panic right now to get this installed right. Any help will be much appreciated.

I'm running PC with Windows 7 installed and I just installed Microsoft Visual Studio Express C# 2010 and Microsoft XNA Game Studio 4.0.

Please give step by step instructions if possible. Thanks for taking the time read this post!

Answer (score 1):

Start Visual C# & create a new project. You should be able to choose either Windows Game or Xbox 360 Game as your project type.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I just reinstalled XNA Game Studio 4.0, loaded visual studio and then clicked on XNA Game Studio 4.0 under Installed Templates. Hope this helps.